# How to display user defined column name in yajra datatables

Tags: laravel, datatables

i am trying to view datatables where i have user defined columns. It is showing the name of table column automatically.

i have a class IncomesourceDatatable and from that class i am rendering to my view
below i have a function getColumns.

```
protected function getColumns()
{
 return [
    'title',
    'description',
    'special_rule',
    'amount',
    'created_at',
 ];
}
```

Comment: You want to get specific column on collection or remove unwanted column from collection?

Comment: i want to put user defined comlumn in view, not exacly the database comlumn name. like in case of title i will show my title, special rule shows as "Special Rule" but want to give name as Rules.. like simple i want to put a name on the view by myself, not the exact column name